# N.Alon, J.Spencer Probabilistic methods problem ch. $4$ problem $5$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $v_1=(x_1,y_1),...,v_n=(x_n,y_n)$ be $n$ two dimensional vectors where each $x_i$ and each $y_i$ is an integer whose absolute value does not exceed $2^{n/2}/(100 \sqrt{n})$. Show that there are two disjoint sets $I,J \subset \{ 1,2,...,n\}\ $ such that   $ \ \ \sum \limits_{i \in I} v_i = \sum \limits_{j \in J} v_j$

I tried to use the fact that $Pr[X>0] \leq \mathbb{E}[X] \ $ where $X$ is a non negative random variable. In particular I defined $X= \sum \limits_{j \in J} v_i - \sum \limits_{i \in I} v_i$. $\ \ $  But I am not sure about choosing $I,J$ in the right way. Any help on this would be much appreciate.

Comment: I have not solved the problem, but it seems like a pigeonhole principle problem. I'd try to count how many nonempty subsets like $I$ or $J$ there are (say $n$), how many possible values $\sum_{i\in I}v_i$ can have (say $m$). If $n>m$ there will be two different subsets with the same sum. Remove common elements and they will be disjoint.

Comment: @ClementC. it's componentwise addition. Vector addition i.e $v_{i_1}+v_{i_2}=(x_{i_1}+x_{i_2},y_{i_1}+y_{i_2})$ ...from what i understood

Comment: Yes, I figured afterwards. (And deleted my comment accordingly)

Comment: @sigma I will not go through it (unless you are completely stuck), but look at the outline/hints from [this](https://www.nada.kth.se/kurser/kth/2D5323/00-01/ps2.pdf) (Exercise 7).

Answer (score 5):

I remind you, this book is totally systematic, a question from chapter 4 will be solved using the second moment method:

Define the random variables: $\epsilon_i=Ber(\frac1 2)$

Define a random variable $X=\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon _i v_i$ and compute the mean of each coordinate:
$$\mu_x =\frac1 2 \sum_{i\leq n}x_i\space,\space \mu_y =\frac1 2 \sum_{i\leq n}y_i$$
compute the variances:
$$\sigma_x^2 =\frac1 4 \sum_{i\leq n}x^2_i\space,\space \sigma_y^2 =\frac1 4 \sum_{i\leq n}y^2_i$$
Both of the are bounded by $\frac{2^n}{40000}$. By Chebyshev, we get for any $\lambda$:
$$Pr[|X_x − \mu_x| \geq \frac{λ · 2^{n/2}}{200}] ≤ λ^{−2}$$
$$Pr[|X_y − \mu_y| \geq \frac{λ · 2^{n/2}}{200}] ≤ λ^{−2}$$
The probability that both are false is at least $1 − 2λ^{
−2}$
. In the box delineated by these
two inequalities there are at most $λ^
2 2^
n/10000$ lattice points, so if every value of $ X $ occurs at
most once,
$$(1-2\lambda^{-2})2^n\leq \frac{\lambda^2 2^n}{10000}$$
since there are $2^n$
total values of $X$. Picking $λ = 2$ is enough to see a contradiction. Thus
X takes some vector value twice, i.e. there exist distinct subsets $I, J \subseteq [1, n] $ for which
$$\sum_Iv_i=\sum_Jv_j$$

Removing the intersection $I \cap J$ from both sets we still have equal sums, as desired.

Comment: In the computation of variences, should it be \leq instead of equal?