# Question about the book probabilistic methods, Noga Alon, Joel Spencer

Tags: reference-request

$\textbf{Question}$: Does anybody know of someone who took the time to write down some or most of the solutions to this book (The probabilistic method by N. Alon, J.Spencer)  in $\LaTeX$ ?

If so, are they available to the public?

Once I found a pdf file online by a student who took the time to  do this but sadly he took it offline. It would be great to have some solutions or alternative point of views on some problms since it accelerates the learning process a lot.

Comment: What about just posting the questions you have been working on on this website, along with your solution, and ask for alternatives?

Comment: @ClementC. I tried a couple of times but I often get no answers

Comment: I can only see one, from two days ago ([link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077195/n-alon-j-spencer-probabilistic-methods-problem-ch-4-probem-5)). Is that what you are referring to? If so, give it some time. It's only been two days, and was posted the day before New Year's Eve...

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I also posted before that and deleted the questions. But yes I will give it some time. Thanks for your time

Comment: I'll try to give it a shot later. Worst-case scenario, if it doesn't pan out one can still promise a bounty.